# c# how to put a clamp on ball speed

Tags: c#, xna, projectile

I have a ball for brick breaker, when it bounces off the bat on the edges it speeds up past 4 and -4. How could i put a clamp on say the X direction so that the ball doesn't go past 4 or -4?

Any helps or tips are much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: [Apparently, XNA has the `MathHelper` class which has a `Clamp` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.clamp.aspx).

See below if you want to implement it yourself.

---

A typical clamp function is `max(minimum, min(value, maximum))`.

That is, something like

```
ball.Velocity.X = Math.Max(-4, Math.Min(ball.Velocity.X, 4))
```

The call to `Min` limits the value to at most 4 (if it is larger than 4, 4 is now smaller so `Min` returns 4) and the call to `Max` limits the value to at least -4 (if it is less than -4, -4 is now larger so `Max` returns -4.

Combined, the two clamp the value.